# is it safe that multi elastic search client create the same index at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch, race-condition

is it safe that multi elastic search client create the same index at the same time?

An example is using date as index name, when a new day came, many clients will try to write to a not exist index, and this will lead to create a new index.

I didn't found related information from official documents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with writing to a non existing index is that it creates an index(probably without the mapping that you wish for). However you don't need to worry about creating another index with the same name because it won't happen.